# How hide and show master in landscape?

Tags: sapui5

I have my application and I run it in my desktop screen 
If I use resize the window (width) the master bar is hidden and I can open it by the icon on te top-left corner.
This is the output in this mode
[image: The correct output]

I would like this behavior also in full-screen mode on my desktop screen, but now I have this result:
[image: The wrong output]

How I can reach the output that I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the mode of the splitapp.

Here is the official docu:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitAppMode.html

Here is a working example.
http://jsbin.com/butedoquyo/1/edit?html,output

BR,
Tobias

Comment: It is in the upper left corner of the detail page. It's three horizontal lines